# Having problem with digits recognition in python using opencv, tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying crop an image using opencv and then let tesseract read it, but even the image is quite clear it is not able to recognize numbers out of that image, here are lines of code for the action:

```
screen_img = cv2.imread(f'data\\screenshot\\{e_name}.png')
crop_img = screen_img[350:385,185:270]
crop_img = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(f'data\\screenshot{e_name}.png',crop_img)
cv2.imshow('ad',crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_img)
print(text)
```

The output of `cv2.imshow('ad',crop_img)` look something like this:[image]

But the output of `print(text)` is nothing other a new blank line in the console.

I really appreciate for your help (I may making silly mistake since i'm not a professional programmer, then i'm sorry about that).

EDIT1: I've added a few line thanks to the comments:

```
screen_img = cv2.imread(f'data\\screenshot\\{e_name}.png')
crop_img = screen_img[350:385,185:270]
crop_img = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
crop_img = cv2.bitwise_not(crop_img)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(crop_img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('ad',thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh1)
```

The output now look much more promising:[image]

But the result seem to remain the same,i've check some random text image from the internet and most of them work just fine.

Comment: Apply inverse binary threshold (Otsu), to make sure the text is in black

Comment: Tesseract needs black text on white background. Invert the image before passing it to the OCR engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A magic happens when adding `config='--psm 6'`.

According to [Tesseract OCR options page](https://muthu.co/all-tesseract-ocr-options/):

> 6 Assume a single uniform block of text.

---

Code sample:

```
crop_img = cv2.imread('crop_img.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_img, config='--psm 6')
print(text)
```

---

Result:
`73.9`